# Duplicate rows in dataframe based on column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have a task at hand, where I want to prepare input for same size clustering algorithm.
The input contains duplicate rows for observations that are more important and weight of importance is provided as number of rows.

Anyway, I have a dataframe that has desired number of rows in a column. Is there some simple way of creating duplicates in the dataframe?

Here is an example:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Letter': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
               'Duplicate': [2, 1, 3, 1]})

print(df)
Out[118]: 
      Duplicate Letter
0          2      A
1          1      B
2          3      C
3          1      D
```

My desired output looks like this:

```
Out[117]: 
   Duplicate Letter
0          2      A
1          2      A
2          1      B
3          3      C
4          3      C
5          3      C
6          1      D
```

Is there some simple way of doing this? This is how I got there:

```
# create a list of duplicate unique keys
dup_list = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    dup_list.append([df.loc[i,'Letter']]*int(df.loc[i,'Duplicate']))

# make the list flat
flat_list = list(itertools.chain(*dup_list))

# create DF from the list
join_df = pd.DataFrame(flat_list, columns=['Letter'])

# and finally join two dataframes to multiply rows
merge_df = pd.merge(df, join_df, on='Letter')
print(merge_df) # the desired result
```

Maybe some lambda expression would be simpler?

thanks

Comment: Do you still need the 'duplicate' column afterwards? Cause if not it might be a lot simpler to just generate a list of replicas and then build a pandas series or dataframe from it. Edit: nevermind, np.repeat as in the question this was marked as duplicate is simple enough

Comment: Yes I need the columns, because the real dataframe has more than two columns. @john-galt, thanks, I didn't notice this solution before, as I wasn't also looking at numpy functions only pandas...

Comment: Or `df.set_index('Letter').Duplicate.repeat(df.Duplicate).reset_index()` it's the same. This has been answered multiple times here Stefan.

Comment: @JohnGalt - thanks, I wasn't looking enough today. Is the correct way to delete my question now? thanks